# How to convert an array of AnyRef to a tuple of Ints

Tags: scala

I needed to convert an array of AnyRef (java function argument) to a tuple of Ints. I tried the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585549/convert-an-array-to-a-tuple-elegantly-in-scala), but this didn't work for me because in that question it was assumed that the array was an array of Any, not an array of AnyRef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the code that worked for me looked as follows:

```
val (x, y) = args match { case Array(x: Integer, y: Integer, _*) => (x, y) }
```

Note the use of the boxing class Integer rather than Int to deal with the fact that we are sourcing from auto-boxed AnyRefs (java Objects).

Comment: Note that scala automatically handles the boxed/unboxed duality, so you keep using scala's `Int` instead of `java.lang.Integer` (provided that you type the array properly as `Array[_]` instead of `Array[AnyRef]`): `val (x, y) = (args:Array[_]) match { case Array(x: Int, y: Int) => (x, y) }`