# Can I write a scala function that returns an n-tuple where n is defined by an argument?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a scala function that generates n-grams from tweets.

The function will take two arguments, firstly a list of strings (the tweets we want to examine), and an integer n. If we set n to 2 (the default), then the result of the function will be a HashMultiset of 2-tuples, likewise if we set it to 3 then the result will be a HashMultiset of 3-tuples.

Is there any way to define such a function? I'd like to be explicit with my typing, so I'd prefer not to just define the function as returning a MultiSet of Any.

Here's the stub function I have so far, it only works for n==2:

```
def extract_ngrams(tweets:List[String], n:Int=2):HashMultiset[(String,String)] = {
val result = HashMultiset.create[(String,String)]()
result.add(("a", "a"))
result
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tuples in Scala go only up to 22. So even if there was a possibility it would only allow n values of 2..22.

I would instead simply return `HashMultiset[Array[String]]` and you can use n to define your result arity:
`val result = HashMultiset[Array[String]].create()`

You could then [map it to tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585549/convert-an-array-to-a-tuple-elegantly-in-scala) depending on the use case when needed.

*Update*

If I understand what you need, I would do something like

```
def extract_ngrams(tweets:List[String], n:Int=2):Map[List[String],Int] = {
   tweets.sliding(n).toList.groupBy(_.toList).mapValues(_.length)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible with the native Scala libraries.  You can use something like [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) if this functionality is important to you.

The common supertype of the tuples you're describing is `Product with Serializable`, so you could return a `HashMultiset[Product with Serializable]` if you wanted to, but you're probably better of just returning a `HashMultiset[Seq[String]]` or `HashMultiset[Map[Int, String]]` or `HashMultiset[Array[String]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that a tuple may be the wrong data structure. A case class could solve this neatly:

```
case class Data(v: String*)

def makeData(v: String*) = {
  Data(v: _*)
}

val s = Set[Data]()

s += makeData("a", "b")
s += makeData("c", "d", "e")

for(i <- s) i match {
  case Data(v @ _*) => println(v)
}
```