# Converting command line argument key=value pair to Map in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

in my main program i receive inputs like -
key1=value1 key2=value2

Now what I want is to create a map out of it. I know the imperative way of doing this where I would get Array[String] that can be foreach and then split by "=" and then key and value can be used to form a Map.

is there a good functional and readable way to achieve this? 
Also It will be great if I can avoid mutable Map and I want to avoid initial Dummy value initialization.

```
  def initialize(strings: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val m = collection.mutable.Map("dummy" -> "dummyval")
    strings.foreach(
      s => {
        val keyVal:Array[String] = s.split("=")

        m += keyVal(0) -> keyVal(1)

      })
    println(m)
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just use [toMap()](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array@toMap[T,U]:scala.collection.Map[T,U]).

However, converting from array to tuple is not quite trivial:
[How to convert an Array to a Tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585549/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-tuple)

```
scala> val ar = Array("key1=value1","key2=value2")
ar: Array[String] = Array(key1=value1, key2=value2)

scala> ar.collect(_.split("=") match { case Array(x,y) => (x,y)}).toMap
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2)
```

Maybe you have to call `Function.unlift` for intellij

```
val r = ar.collect(Function.unlift(_.split("=") match { case Array(x, y) => Some(x, y)})).toMap
```

Comment: error coming "can not resolve reference collect to such signature" in intellij.

Comment: more precise error - type mismatch, expected PartialFunction[String, NotInferedB], actual (Any) => (T,T)

Comment: yes.. thanks so much. i wonder if intellij can fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

similar to above but using only 'map'

```
ar.map(_.split("=")).map(a=>(a(0), a(1))).toMap
```

Comment: then its your IDE, try using File->Invalidates caches and restart. You can always verify one line solutions in scala repl just to be sure your IDE is not messing with you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) to do the command line argument parsing in a neat way.

Comment: u don't always have luxury to use any open source as per your convenience :)

Comment: It was a suggestion my friend. :)