# How to convert between java to scala datatype nested

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I have a function which is returning `List<String[]>` , I can modify it to return something else also, In scale the function I am calling is expecting input as: `Seq[Product]`

I am getting following error:

```
[scalac-2.11]  found   : List[Array[String]]
[scalac-2.11]  required: Seq[Product]
```

I am new to scala, how can I do the same?

The api I need to call is expecting input like:

```
 Seq( ("id", "string", "id", "string"), ("my_date", "string", "my_date", "string") )) )
```

Comment: It seems odd that your expected datatype is `Product`. That's a very base-level datatype, quite close to `Any` (the Scala equivalent of `Object`). Are you sure `Product` is the input type you want?

Comment: I am glue a glue api, which expect input in following format:
applyMapping(
      Seq(
        ("id",                                        "string", "id", "string"),
        ("my_date",                                   "string", "my_date", "string")
      ))
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to [transform `List[Array[String]] => List[scala.Product]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585694/432903) in order to match input type of api you are calling.

**Say, your api looks like:**

```
scala> def glueApi(data: Seq[Product]) = "do something"
glueApi: (data: Seq[Product])String
```

**transformation: `List[Array[String]] => List[scala.Product]`**

```
scala> val data = List(Array("id", "001", "id2", "002"), Array("date1", "data1", "date2", "data2"))
data: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(id, 001, id2, 002), Array(date1, data1, date2, data2))

scala> val dataProducts:List[Product] = data.map { case Array(a, b, c, d) => (a, b, c, d) }
dataProducts: List[Product] = List((id,001,id2,002), (date1,data1,date2,data2))
```

**call api:**

```
scala> glueApi(dataProducts)
res3: String = do something
```

***Note:** `TupleN` is impl of `ProductN`.* - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Tuple4.html

```
case class Tuple4[+T1, +T2, +T3, +T4](_1: T1, _2: T2, _3: T3, _4: T4)
  extends Product4[T1, T2, T3, T4]
{
  override def toString() = "(" + _1 + "," + _2 + "," + _3 + "," + _4 + ")"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Array`s are each of fixed size 4 (based on your sample data), for each of the `Array`s in the list, you can use pattern matching to extract the `Array` elements into a `Tuple4`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val arrList: java.util.List[Array[String]] = ArrayBuffer(
    Array("id", "string", "id", "string"),
    Array("my_date", "string", "my_date", "string")
  ).asJava
// arrList: java.util.List[Array[String]] = [[Ljava.lang.String;@1f50fe84, [Ljava.lang.String;@3380313d]

val productList: Seq[Product] = arrList.asScala.
  map{ case Array(s1, s2, s3, s4) => (s1, s2, s3, s4) }
// productList: Seq[Product] = ArrayBuffer(
//   (id,string,id,string), (my_date,string,my_date,string)
// )
```

Note that `Tuple4` is a canonical representation of `Product4`, which in turn extends `Product`.  For common conversions between Java and Scala collections, here's a relevant [doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert your arrays to `Tuple4`s. If you can guarantee that your arrays are always of size 4, and assuming they're in the same order that the tuples require, then you could simply do this:

```
myList.map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2), arr(3)))
```

However, if you cannot guarantee your arrays are of size 4 or if the array elements are out of order relative to the tuple requirements, then you'll have to do some extra work to deal with those cases.